# Approach to overriding a Core Data property: isDeleted

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I'd like to override the `isDeleted` property in `NSManagedObject` since it isn't being used in my application, and when it's accidentally been used in the past, subtle bugs were introduced. With that goal in mind, I was thinking of doing something like the following, and simply having all my `NSManagedObject` types inherit from this parent. Is this an optimal approach for what I'm looking to do?

```
@interface CustomManagedObject : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDeleted, readonly) BOOL deleted;
@end

@implementation CustomManagedObject

- (BOOL)isDeleted
{
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Did you mean isDeleted, because that is not allowed...!");
}

// ....

@end
```

Comment: I think you want NSAssert(false, @"...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following is more elegant to have:

```
@interface CustomManagedObject : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDeleted, readonly) BOOL deleted __attribute__((unavailable));
@end
```

Or

```
@interface CustomManagedObject : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, getter=isDeleted, readonly) BOOL deleted __attribute__((deprecated));
@end
```

Give them a try.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! For anyone reading this, more info on `__attribute__` here: http://nshipster.com/__attribute__/