# Singleton with parameter iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

I need to implement a singleton class that takes in a parameter. The same object will be passed as a parameter every single time so the resultant singleton object will always be the same.

I am doing something like the code below. Does this look ok? Is there a better way of achieving what I want to achieve?

```
  - (id)sharedInstanceWithAccount:(UserAccount *)userAccount {
      if (!sharedInstance) {
        @synchronized(self) {
          sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] initWithAccount:userAccount];
        }
      }

      return sharedInstance;
    }

    - (id)initWithAccount:(UserAccount *)userAccount {
      self = [super init];
      if (self) {
        _userAccount = userAccount;
      }

      return self;
    }

    - (id)init {
      NSAssert(false,
               @"You cannot init this class directly. It needs UserAccountDataSource as a paramter");
      return nil;
    }

    + (id)alloc {
      @synchronized(self) {
        NSAssert(sharedInstance == nil, @"Attempted to allocated a second instance of the singleton");
        sharedInstance = [super alloc];
        return sharedInstance;
      }
      return nil;
    }
```

Comment: This is probably another indication as to why singletons are a bad idea.  You would probably be better of using dependency injection in this case

Comment: But how would I pass in the userAccount object even if I were to use dependency injection?

Comment: You would call `initWithAccount` when you instantiate `MyClass` and then pass this object to all other classes that need your `MyClass` instance

Comment: I'm sorry maybe i'm not understanding this correct. Isn't this the same thing happening in the below function  - (id)sharedInstanceWithAccount:(UserAccount *)userAccount {
      if (!sharedInstance) {
        @synchronized(self) {
          sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] initWithAccount:userAccount];
        }
      }

      return sharedInstance;
    }

Comment: The problem with a singleton with a parameter is that there is the potential for two different calls to `sharedInstanceWithAccount` to pass different accounts (I know you say you won't but it is still possible).  You can either use a factory pattern as per the answer with a dictionary, or just forget about singletons, instantiate the single class instance and pass it to every class that needs it using dependency injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problem in this design:

1. As recommended by Apple, should `dispatch_once` instead of `@synchronized(self)` for singleton:

   ```
   static MyClass *sharedInstance = nil;
   static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
   });
   return sharedInstance;
   ```

   Refer to this question for more detail: [Why does Apple recommend to use dispatch_once for implementing the singleton pattern under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119042/why-does-apple-recommend-to-use-dispatch-once-for-implementing-the-singleton-pat)
2. Bad `API` design to put singleton in `alloc`.

   As indicated by the name of the method `alloc`, it means that some memory will be allocated. However, in your case, it is not. This attempt to overwrite the `alloc` will cause confusion to other programmers in your team.
3. Bad idea to use `NSAssert` in your `-init`.

   If you want to disable a method, disable it by putting this in your header file:

   ```
   - (id)init __attribute__((unavailable));
   ```

   In this case, you will get a compile error instead of crashing the app at run time. 
   Refer to this post for more detail: [Approach to overriding a Core Data property: isDeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078875/approach-to-overriding-a-core-data-property-isdeleted/28079708#28079708)

   Moreover, you can even add unavailable message:

   ```
   - (id)init __attribute__((unavailable("You cannot init this class directly. It needs UserAccountDataSource as a parameter")));
   ```
4. Sometime input parameters is ignored with no warning.

   In your following code, how would the programmer who is calling this function know that the input parameter `userAccount` is sometimes ignored if an instance of the class is already created by someone else?

   ```
   - (id)sharedInstanceWithAccount:(UserAccount *)userAccount {
       if (!sharedInstance) {
           @synchronized(self) {
              sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] initWithAccount:userAccount];
           }
       }
       return sharedInstance;
   }
   ```

In short, don't think it is a good idea to create singleton with parameter. Use conventional singleton design is much cleaner.

Comment: So how can I achieve what I am trying then? I want just one copy of this class to exist in the app and it depends on UserAccount.

Comment: Yes, if you use singleton, you will have only one copy of the class. If you want it to depends on UserAccount, just modify that value after you acquired the singleton.

Comment: Thats true. I mean how can I pass the UserAccount object to the class without taking in a parameter when constructing the class? I can make it a property and set it later but there's again a problem if someone forgets to set the property.

Comment: Okay, could you take a look at my edits to the question? Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
objA = [Object sharedInstanceWithAccount:A];
objB = [Object sharedInstanceWithAccount:B];
```

B is ignored. 
userAccount in objB is A.

if userAccount B in objB, you will change sharedInstanceWithAccount.

```
- (id)sharedInstanceWithAccount:(UserAccount *)userAccount {
    static NSMutableDictionary *instanceByAccount = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    id instance = instanceByAccount[userAccount];

    if (!instance) {
        @synchronized(self) {
            instance = [[[self class] alloc] initWithAccount:userAccount];
            instanceByAccount[userAccount] = instance;
        }
    }

    return instance;
}
```